# Как скрыть консоль обновления mysql?

Tags: mysql

Каждый день при обновлении mysql вижу как она при этом распахивает окно и запускает терминал с выводом своего лога. Просмотрел её настройки ничего похожего на скрытие этого консольного окна не нашел. Как сделать что бы она продолжала обновятся но при этом не показывала консоль?

ps

mysql 5.7

Comment: Где какое окно, какая ОС, какой компьютер?

Comment: @andreymal ОС win7 , каждый день в строго определенное время (по вечерам) открывается консольное окно в котором видно как обновляется mysql. и не у меня одного. ставил на две разные винды через штатный инсталятор и ничего от этого не меняется вылазит все равно.

Comment: Что такое "обновление mysql"? Вы сервер каждый день обновляете? Или у Вас кто-то обновляет базу?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov это обновление так настроено по умолчанию

Answer (score 1):

Выяснилось. При установки она добавляет запланированное задание в планировщик.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сделал так. Не знаю поможет ли...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]